# Fiz esse código join, consegui que ele me retornasse os valores esperados, porém os valores aparecem repetidos. (obs: sou iniciante em Banco de dados)

Tags: mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```sql
select CLI_NOME, TEC_TELEFONE from tb_clientes 
 join tb_tel_clientes on   CLI_BAI_CODIGO = CLI_BAI_CODIGO 
 where CLI_BAI_CODIGO in(2,3,4) order by CLI_NOME;
```

Comment: Não consegui identificar valores repetidos na imagem que você apresentou.

Comment: o cli_nome na imagem, João maria aparece várias vezes, e os outros clientes que correspondem tanto aos bairros 3 e 4, acontece o mesmo

Comment: Mas aparecem junto com diferentes telefones, o que é o esperado para um select com uma operação de junção.

Comment: vdd, depois de fazer de 3 formas diferentes eu parei pra observar isso, obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Não conhecendo a estrutura da tabela, parece que o campo `CLI_BAI_CODIGO` só pertence a uma coluna (caso contrário o motor de BD queixar-se-ia de não conseguir saber a que tabela o campo ser referiria).

Por este motivo, a condição de junção tal como está é equivalente a " 1 = 1 " ou seja sempre verdadeira (o comportamento seria o mesmo se não estivesse sequer presente). Quando isto acontece, o resultado obtido é a combinação de todas as linhas da primeira tabela com todas as linhas da segunda tabela (operaçao também chamada `produto interno`). Sobre este espaço de resultado é aplicado o filtro sobre as linhas que se referem ao `CLI_BAI_CODIGO IN (2,3,4)``.

Juntanto tudo isto, a primeira coluna aparece duplicada (porque pertence à mesma tabela que o campo `CLI_BAI_CODIGO`.

Espero que ajude a perceber o comportamento, mas como disse no início, sem os detalhes do esquema não é possível dar detalhes sem ser especulação.